# Populating GUI listview on a single line

Tags: winforms, powershell

Trying to workout why the below function (executed from a GUI button) does not place all the output on the same line in the GUI listview. Each command in the function places the output one line down in the list view from the previous command. Tried piping commands, variables and arrays without success.

[image: Gui_Listview]

```
Function Get-MailboxSizeQuotasTool {
    Get-Mailbox $WPFinputbox.Text |
        Select-Object @{Name='Display Name';Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
                      @{Name='Prohibit Send Quota';Expression={$_.ProhibitSendQuota}},
                      @{Name='Use Database Defaults';Expression={$_.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults}},
                      @{Name='Archive Quota';Expression={$_.ArchiveQuota}}

    Get-MailboxStatistics $WPFinputbox.Text |
        Select-Object @{Name='Mailbox Size';Expression={$_.TotalItemSize}}
    Get-MailboxStatistics $WPFinputbox.Text -Archive |
        Select-Object @{Name='Archive Size';Expression={$_.TotalItemSize}}
}

$WPFokbutton.Add_Click({
    $WPFlist.Items.Clear()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 840
    Get-MailboxSizeQuotasTool -Identity $WPFinputbox.Text |
        % {$WPFlist.AddChild($_)}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function outputs 3 different objects with different properties. You need to consolidate the information in a single object:

```
Function Get-MailboxSizeQuotasTool {
  $mailbox = Get-Mailbox $WPFinputbox.Text

  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'Display Name'          = $mailbox.DisplayName
    'Prohibit Send Quota'   = $mailbox.ProhibitSendQuota
    'Use Database Defaults' = $mailbox.UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults
    'Archive Quota'         = $mailbox.ArchiveQuota
    'Mailbox Size'          = Get-MailboxStatistics $WPFinputbox.Text |
                              Select-Object -Expand TotalItemSize
    'Archive Size'          = Get-MailboxStatistics $WPFinputbox.Text -Archive |
                              Select-Object -Expand TotalItemSize
    }
}
```